# Get data frame for a list of column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a simple `pandas` `DataFrame` instance defined as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
timestamps = [1, 2, 3]
is_events_1 = [False, True, True]
is_events_2 = [True, False, True]
is_censored = [False, True, False]
data = dict(is_events_1=is_events_1, is_events_2=is_events_2, is_censored=is_censored)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=data.keys(), index=timestamps)
```

which looks like this:

```
   is_events_1  is_events_2  is_censored
1        False         True        False
2         True        False         True
3         True         True        False
```

**Is there any way to get the `data_frame` values for `is_events_1` and `is_events_2` only?** I tried the following:

```
print(df['is_events_1', 'is_events_2'])
```

but get the error *KeyError: ('is_events_1', 'is_events_2')*.

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: You need to pass a list `print(df[['is_events_1', 'is_events_2']])` this has been asked before

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass it as a list.

```
print(df[['is_events_1', 'is_events_2']])
```